# Vários resultados em um único registro - Oracle

Tags: oracle, select

Estou com a seguinte situação: tenho um `select` onde me retorna que o paciente TESTE passou na clinica ABC, e realizou procedimento 01 e 02, porém no resultado da **query** ele me retorna assim **texto em negrito**:

### Paciente | Clinica | Procedimento   |

Teste    | ABC     | 01             |
Teste    | ABC     | 02             |

**Porém eu precisava do seguinte resultado:**

### Paciente | Clinica | Procedimento   |

Teste    | ABC     | 01 - 02        |

Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

função listagg resolve

```
select paciente
     , clinica
     , listagg(procedimento, ' - ') within group (order by procedimento)   procedimento
from tabela
group by paciente, clinica
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas no meu caso não estou conseguindo fazer agrupa, ele esta ficando assim:                                                                              teste | paciente | exame 1, exame 2                                                                                teste | paciente | exame 2, exame 1

Comment: Diogo, é estranho esse comportamento, porque o listagg vai seguir o agrupamento que consta no "group by", e a ordem dentro do listagg. Pode existir algum outro campo fora do "group by" que cause isso. Não quer colocar o select que vc esta usando, a estrutura da tabela e uns 10 registros como exemplo pra análise?

Comment: Dessa deu certo, eu refiz a query e agrupou, só fiquei com uma duvida, quando eu tento extrair todos os registros encontrado, esta dando erro de oracle-01489, voce saberia me disse se existe limite para concatenar ? Agradeço sua ajuda @fabioceron.

Comment: Esse limite é dado pelo banco, que considera essa operação no select como uma coluna varchar2, com limite de 4000 caracteres. Se você, em tempo de execução, mudar essa coluna para clob, por exemplo, não dá esse erro, mas aí você vai ter que tratar a coluna clob. Antes, veja se os requisitos não podem ser mais restritos (intervalo de tempo menor, intervalo de clinicas/pacientes menor, etc).