# Problema na hora de gravar dados

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

Estou realizando uma consulta em uma tabela onde a estrutura é :

```
Documento  Produto
123        Camisa Posh rosa
127        Calça Handara 36
127        Meia Barby 
158        Calça Handara 38
129        Blusa Yoll M
129        Blusa Yoll azul P
129        Short preto 36
```

No Python criei um curso pra esta consulta, pois o meu intuito e gravar o resulta em uma *string* separada por `,`, porém dessa forma:

```
Camisa Posh rosa,
Calça Handara 36, Meia Barby ,
Calça Handara 38,
Blusa Yoll M, Blusa Yoll azul P, Short preto 36
```

Neste caso ele pegaria os produtos que estão em no mesmo cupom e gravaria em uma unica linha, mas o meu problema é que ele está duplicando a quantidade de registro para estes documentos:

```
Camisa Posh rosa,
Calça Handara 36, Meia Barby ,
Calça Handara 36, Meia Barby ,
Calça Handara 38,
Blusa Yoll M, Blusa Yoll azul P, Short preto 36   
Blusa Yoll M, Blusa Yoll azul P, Short preto 36 
Blusa Yoll M, Blusa Yoll azul P, Short preto 36
```

Acredito que tenho que criar um FOR para checar os cupons e não repetir os dados, porem não estou conseguindo jogar está logica no código. Segue o código

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\oracle\\product\\10.2.0\\client")
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('venda/venda@1.1.1.100:1521/local')

curVendas = con.cursor()
curVendaProd = con.cursor()
base = ''

curVendas.execute('select * from base_venda')
for vendas in curVendas:
    print(vendas)

    quantidade = curVendaProd.execute('select produto from base_venda where documento = ' + str(vendas[0]))
    i = 1
    for produtos in curVendaProd:
        print(produtos)

        if (i == quantidade) :
            base = base + produtos[0]
        else:
            base = base + produtos[0] + ',' 
            i += 1

    base = base + '\n'

arquivo = open("base_import.csv", "w")
arquivo.write(base)
arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Você não precisa fazer a lógica no Python, pois já consegue obter o resultado desejado direto do banco de dados fazendo o `GROUP BY` pelo número do documento e concatenando os produtos.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Vários resultados em um único registro - Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225417/5878)

Comment: Anderson obrigada pela interação realmente usando o LISTAGG concatena como eu quero porem retorna este erro devido a ter muitos registro.ora-01489 result of string concatenation is too long

Comment: Fez o `group by`?

Comment: Sim! Se eu usar uma restrição na quantidade de registro funciona normalmente, porem se form em cima da base ele retorna este erro. Estou pesquisando que existe uma função xmlagg pra base com muitos registro, estou vendo como aplico.

Comment: O `group by` já deveria resolver o problema de registros repetidos no resultado. Se ainda está repetindo, você deve estar fazendo alguma coisa errada.

Comment: Na verdade ele resolveu, não tenho mais registro repetidos, só não consigo visualizar todos os dados na consulta pois apresenta o erro que te falei, na verdade o problema não está no script que você mandou e sim em minha base ter muitos registros.